# Compare the presence of a column in a DF into another DF, then fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DF where I want to check if df1["A"] is in df2. If not fill df2["A"] with 0.

I got it with and ugly for loop and I try to optimize this but I cannot find out how to do it.

```
testing_list = list(testing_df.columns)

for i in range(len(training_df.columns)):
    if not training_df.columns[i] in testing_list:
        testing_df[training_df.columns[i]] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with new columns created by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
testing_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

training_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],

})

cols = testing_df.columns.union(training_df.columns, sort=False)
df = testing_df.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   A  B  F  C  D
0  a  4  a  0  0
1  b  5  a  0  0
2  c  4  a  0  0
3  d  5  b  0  0
4  e  5  b  0  0
5  f  4  b  0  0
```

If want add columns for both DataFrames with sorted columns use [`DataFrame.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

```
testing_df, training_df = testing_df.align(training_df, fill_value=0)
print (testing_df)
   A  B  C  D  F
0  a  4  0  0  a
1  b  5  0  0  a
2  c  4  0  0  a
3  d  5  0  0  b
4  e  5  0  0  b
5  f  4  0  0  b

print (training_df)
   A  B  C  D  F
0  a  0  7  1  0
1  b  0  8  3  0
2  c  0  9  5  0
3  d  0  4  7  0
4  e  0  2  1  0
5  f  0  3  0  0
```

Comment: You again !
Why the sort=False ?

Comment: @Ragnar - Only for avoid sorting columns, you can test if remove it - output is similar like second answer.

Comment: What if I want to do the reverse, If the column is not available in train, drop it in test.
A simple testing_df = testing_df[training_df.columns] doesn't work for columns not present (KeyError)

Comment: I want to check columns wise, not on the index

Comment: @Ragnar - Then use `cols = testing_df.columns.intersection(training_df.columns, sort=False)`